# What does the pandas groupby only return?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I noticed in some of my code I was doing different operations on the same groupby call. So I made only one call:

```
c = df.groupby("SP")
```

And ran different operations on the 'DataFrameGroupBy' object, such as:

```
c["SP"].cumsum()
```

And several others, most of them were of the cumsum, transform type, so same index expected.

So far so good, this sped the script somewhat, but than I noticed that I occassionaly added attributes to the original df after I had made the groupby object (c). This attributes were used on groupby operations. It seems to have worked fine.

But when some rows are droped from the df than the aggregate operations on c are still being done on the old df with all the rows.

So what is the DataFrameGroubBy? is it only a pointer to indices? Or does it make some copy of the DataFrame. From the behavior explained above it appears a copy is made when you change the number of rows in the original DataFrame.

Comment: How did you drop the rows ?   Perhaps, you created a new dataframe while the old one is still being reference by the groupby ?

Comment: df.drop(df.index[condition], inplace=True) I used this.

Comment: This is a very good question and the documentation isn't helpful *Returns a groupby object that contains information about the groups.* I can't find the documentation for *DataFrameGroubBy object*. I didn't knew that you can add columns after grouping, that's nice. After some testing: Aggregations are cached for the dataframe but not for a column, iterating the groups after droping a row leads to *indices are out-of-bounds*. Very interesting.